# Vertical navigation bar must move a bit from top then stay fixed

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to have a vertical navigation bar as in [www.callofduty.com/elite](http://www.callofduty.com/elite). As you can see in this page, to the right there are 3 nav links (CONNECT, COMPETE, IMPROVE). As you scroll down, the nav bar moves down a bit and then stays fixed.

I kindof got scroll-spy, fixed nav working. But the nav bar doesn't move down a bit and stays fixed. It just stays fixed where I positioned it. How to achieve that effect? Any insight would help.

Here is the link to my work http://jsfiddle.net/RJJ2J/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see the [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/anorip/6/)

**Jquery**

```
$(function(){    // this is the shorthand for document.ready
  $(document).scroll(function(){    // this is the scroll event for the document

    scrolltop = $(document).scrollTop(); // by this we get the value of the scrolltop ie how much scroll has been don by user
    if(parseInt(scrolltop) >= 80)    // check if the scroll value is equal to the top of navigation
      { 
        $("#navbar").css({"position":"fixed","top":"0"});   // is yes then make the position fixed to top 0
      }
    else
    {
      $("#navbar").css({"position":"absolute","top":"80px"}); // if no then make the position to absolute and set it to 80
    }
  })

});
```

**CSS**

```
#navbar{
    position: absolute;   // Initially set to absolute so it is movable with the page
    top: 80px; right: 100px;
    /*display: block;*/
    padding-right: 7px;
    background: #fff;
}
```

Comment: it works :-) But can u please explain the script as I'm a beginner in JS. Why console.log(1); and console.log($(this).scrollTop()); ?

Comment: Sorry `console.log` is used to print some thing on console. you can remove them they are just for debugging

Answer (score 0):

use this [waypoints plugin](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/#examples) , It was made to do exactly what you are trying to do

Comment: I want to know how its done..Pluging is not recommended for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @Priya -  i understand ,  I recommended a plugin because constanly monitoring the scrolling event can be bad and slow and others have spent lots of time in getting it right , most of the time I prefer to write things myself , I think this may be a time to use the plugin