# Fixed css menu depending on browser header

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-position

I need help finding jQuery js fixed left menu [like this](http://tringme.com/howitworks.html).

Fixed position scrolling should depends on browser header.

Comment: Can you explain what you need a little more clearly, and describe what you have already tried?

Comment: Please let us know what you have tried, and we could help you better.

Comment: Just look at their code. I found it in under a minute.

Comment: i need right div table to stay fixed while scrolling but it need to be active after the browser header touch top of the side menu like here visit: http://tringme.com/howitworks.html. i need only js demo :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see the answer in [**link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12749982/vertical-navigation-bar-must-move-a-bit-from-top-then-stay-fixed/12750490#12750490)

I  prepared a demo in the answer might it help you

Main thing you need is **jQuery**

```
$(function(){    // this is the shorthand for document.ready
  $(document).scroll(function(){    // this is the scroll event for the document

    scrolltop = $(document).scrollTop(); // by this we get the value of the scrolltop ie how much scroll has been don by user
    if(parseInt(scrolltop) >= 80)    // check if the scroll value is equal to the top of navigation
      { 
        $("#navbar").css({"position":"fixed","top":"0"});   // is yes then make the position fixed to top 0
      }
    else
    {
      $("#navbar").css({"position":"absolute","top":"80px"}); // if no then make the position to absolute and set it to 80
    }
  })

});
```

Comment: Also note position:sticky for the future. http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/08/Stick-your-landings-position-sticky-lands-in-WebKit